# how to detect defect in pcb using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

[image]
I am working on project in which i supposed to detect defect in PCB i have already tried image subtraction method. It detects the defect missing components in PCB but it is not giving correct output even when PCB is not defect. it means it show that there
is missing component in PCB even the component is present

here is me code

```
g_o_img = cv2.cvtColor(o_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
g_def_img = cv2.cvtColor(def_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
score, diff = structural_similarity(g_o_img, g_def_img, full=True)
diff1 = (diff*255).astype("uint8")
cv2.imshow("diff", diff1)

ssim = format(score)
print("SSIM : "+ssim)
l_b = np.array([0])
u_b = np.array([50])
mask = cv2.inRange(diff1, l_b, u_b)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

erode = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel)

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("erode", erode)
```

I have done perspective transformation and i am getting very good output but as my images are of different light illuminations so i am not getting proper output using image subtraction here is my code

```
img1 = cv2.imread("./pcb_images/orig3.png")
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (640, 480))
image1 = img1[10:-10,10:-10]
print(image1)

g_o_img = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)   [...,0]
img2 = cv2.imread("./pcb_images/defect4.png")
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (640, 480)) 
image2 = img2[10:-10,10:-10]
g_def_img = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[...,0]

thresh1 = cv2.threshold(g_o_img, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(g_def_img, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

res = cv2.bitwise_xor(thresh1, thresh2, mask=None)
```

[image: non defective pcb][image: defective pcb]

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some preprocessing before background subtraction. You have to detect the PCB only (without the background) and make sure the perspective is always the same. If the perspective is not the same do some **Perspective Transformation** to crop the PCB out of the image (Check [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)). Then convert the image to a **Color Space** that is more robust to light and shadows (Check [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/)). After that you can do background subtraction followed by **Thresholding** (Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-thresholding-techniques-using-opencv-set-1-simple-thresholding/) )to get a binary image. Finally you can do **Morphological Transformations** to remove the false positives (Check [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/morphological-transformation-python-opencv-tutorial/)) and leave only the differences between the images .

**Solution**

This is the implementation of the approach explained above. You can experiment with different color spaces, threshold values or morphological kernel sizes to see which will give you better results.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)

img1 = cv2.imread("orig.png")
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (640, 480))
image1 = img1[10:-10,10:-10]

img2 = cv2.imread("defect.png")
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (640, 480)) 
image2 = img2[10:-10,10:-10]
#Changing color space
g_o_img = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)   [...,0]
g_def_img = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)[...,0]

#Image subtraction
sub =cv2.subtract(g_o_img, g_def_img)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sub , 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
#Morphological opening 
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


#Detecting blobs
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByInertia = False
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.filterByCircularity = False

im=cv2.bitwise_not(opening)

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

keypoints = detector.detect(im)

#Drawing circle around blobs
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

#Display image with circle around defect
cv2.imshow('image',im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output**

Subtraction Result
[image]

Binary Image
[image]

Defect Image
[image]

Comment: can you please provide me code, because what i have tried is not working

Comment: Show the code of what you have been trying in the question and provide enough images for people to be able to reproduce your problem as this is not a website providing free coding service. Doing image subtraction directly won't work because the camera is not always capturing from the same angle and light conditions and shadows are also not the same.

Comment: above i have share the description of my problem

Comment: Don't put it as an answer Please edit your question and add there then delete the answer.

Comment: Done sir!!!!!!!!!!!Actually i have tried so many times with this as well as  template matching, feature matching  method but i am not getting proper output..please help me